# Can't archive iOS Application (iOS App Archive)

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, build-settings, xcode-organizer

**I KNOW THAT MY QUESTION IS A LOT OF TIMES DISCUSSED**, but no one solution helped me fully (SKIP_INSTALL, copy headers from public and private to Project section and etc.).

**What I have and what I did:**

So, I have a workspace in that I have some projects. I need to archive my project (let's name it **Project1**) for presenting it in the AppStore. I used some classes from other projects in my workspace (for that I added them to ***Edit Scheme-Manage Scheme*** in my **Project1**) I mean I import them.

In my **Project1** and workspace I did:

- set option **SKIP_INSTALL** to YES in **Static Libraries** and NO for **PROJECTS** (and in other projects from that I import classes **I did the same**);
- transfer some headers from **Copy headers** from **public** to **Project** section in the project from that I import classes to my **Project1** as I said before;
- in **Code_Sign_Identity** set **Distribution Provisioning Profile**
- In **Project1** in **Edit Scheme-Archive-Build Configuration** I set Release;
- In **Project1** in **Edit Scheme-Archive-Options** I set ***Reveal Archive*** in Organizer;

**What happens after use Menu-Product-Archive?**

When I press Archive XCode begins work process but when it ends **nothing happens** in Organizer nothing appears.
I found great article (Technical Note) in Apple Docs - [Xcode successfully archived my application, but the Archives Organizer does not list my archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html) but it not helped me. I have already archived another project from that workspace and it worked for that project then, but now for my **Project1**. I think I set something wrong in Build Setting but can't identify what exactly.

What is wrong with my project/workspace?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question by myself. The decision is: in **Build Settings - INSTALL_PATH** set "**$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)**" - this code will generate **/Applications**.

**INSTALL_PATH** install place where XCode will store archive for you.

As I right understand to solve the task about archiving you need to do:

1. in your **PROJECT-SKIP_INSTALL** - set to **NO**, and in your **LIBRARIES-SKIP_INSTALL** - set to **YES**;
2. in your Project set **Build Settings - INSTALL_PATH** set "**$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)**"
3. in **Build Phases-Copy headers** transfer headers from **Public/Private** to **Project** section.

I did these three steps and they are helped me, and I hope they will help you too.